# Translation of Polish writing mailed on back of photograph

Tags: poland, canada, translation, michigan

I'm looking for Polish translation help. A relative recently found a box of materials about deceased relatives. There is a photograph with two women on one side and polish writing on the other (it appears to be a letter but I am not sure who is pictured). It mentions Canada. I'm guessing this might be helpful for context: I had relatives (Parteka family and Bureiza family) who came from Poland. Many in this family also worked on the railroad in Canada, later moving onto buy land in the US. They founded one of the oldest Polish communities in the US (Parisville Michigan). And that Michigan community is near the border with Canada. So maybe these are relatives communicated from the US to Canada.

Added: Here's what I've been able to guess in transcribing and in using google translate so far:

Teraz ja matka prosi i ja marjia more bys ty kochany bracie i bratowo byscie dobre byli a mie przystali na droga bo juz teraz do kanady wdno ja bym wam zahardy dolar 2 razy oddata moze by i w anusuvicow joziak do josmoy to ja bym cherata do wielkiej nocy wiedrieemy wte strone czy wte bo teraz jest pozwolono w kilka panstw bo odnas duzo juz wyjecha wswiat ateraz posylamy wam swoje fortograjie z mamo to prosi was opiscie wy dlomie to ja bede  w robie ztem

Now, my mother and I, Maria, are asking you to be good brother and sister-in-law and I have agreed to the road, because now I will go to Canada, I would give you a dollar twice, I can give you back anusuvicow joziak to josmoy then I would be sick to the great night we see in this side or back because now it is allowed in a few countries because you have already left the world, but now we are sending you our fortograjie with mom, he asks you to describe it further, then I will be  in doing this

[image: Two women pictured]

Comment: What have you been able to transcribe, and what have you been able to translate from that transcription so far?

Comment: I have had good results from the "Genealogy Translations" group on Facebook.

Comment: PolyGeo - I've added that in the edits, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Below is my transcript and translation. I am a Pole, but the text is not easy to read because the author was not proficient in writing. The letter is written along the lines of spoken language, which was also not a literary language but a regional, simplified language.

> Teraz ja matka prosi i ja marja może byś ty kochany bracie i bratowo byście dobre byli a mie przysłali na drogie bo już teraz do kanady wolno ja bym wam za każdy dólar o 2 razy oddała może by co anuszewiców józiak do pomógł to ja  bym chciała do wielkiej nocy wiedzieć czy wte strone czy w wte bo teraz jest pozwolono w kilku państw bo odnas dużo już wyjechało w świat ateraz posyłamy wam swoje fortogragie z mamo to prosi was ogiście wy dlamnie to ja będę e wiedzieć co robie ztem.

This could be modernized to this:

> Teraz ja, matka, proszę, oraz ja, Maria, dołączam się do tej prośby, abyście ty kochany bracie i bratowo uczynili mi przysługę i przysłali pieniądze na drogę, bo już teraz do Kanady wolno nam podróżować. Ja bym wam za każdy dolar dwa razy tyle oddała. Może by też Józef Anuszewicz mi pomógł. Ja bym chciała do nadejścia Wielkanocy wiedzieć czy wyruszę w podróż czy nie, bo teraz pozwolono nam na wyjazd do kilku państw. Od nas dużo osób już wyjechało w świat. Posyłamy wam swoje fotografie z mamą, która to prosi Was. Odpiszcie mi, abym wiedziała co zrobić.

In English:

> Now I, mother, ask you, and I, Maria, join in this request that you dear brother and sister-in-law do me a favor and send me money for the journey, because we are already allowed to travel to Canada. I would return twice as much to you for every dollar. Maybe Joseph Anuszewicz would also help me. I would like to know by the coming of Easter whether I'm going to travel or not, because now we've been allowed to go to several countries. From us, a lot of people have already traveled the world. We are sending you our photographs with my mother, who is asking this of you. Write me back so that I know what to do.

Answer (score -1):

As the writing is fairly clear, you can go to Google Translate and type the text in and it will do a fairly good translation. I've done this with Slovenian letters with success.